# How to remove duplicates in foreach in php

Tags: php

I'm var_dumping from a sql table something like this:

```
<?= "<pre>";  ?>
        <?php var_dump($presents); ?>
<?= "</pre>";  ?>
```

Result:

```
  [40]=>
  object(stdClass)#44 (7) {
    ["PersNr"]=>
    string(4) "101"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(7) "John"
    ["Typ"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(8) "11:43:52"
    ["LastTask"]=>
    string(3) "130"
  }
  [41]=>
  object(stdClass)#45 (7) {
    ["PersNr"]=>
    string(4) "102"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(6) "Maria"
    ["Typ"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(8) "08:01:04"
    ["LastTask"]=>
    string(3) "130"
  }
  [42]=>
  object(stdClass)#46 (7) {
    ["PersNr"]=>
    string(4) "103"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(9) "Jane"
    ["Typ"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["StartTime"]=>
    string(8) "06:54:15"
    ["LastTask"]=>
    string(3) "140"
  }
```

I would like to fetch the LastTask and remove the duplicate

```
<?php foreach($presents as $present) :?>
    <?php echo $present->LastTask ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

With this i get
... 130 130 140 ....
Is there a function to remove the duplicates ?

Comment: Does the data come from a database? if yes, simply change your query. You can use stuff like `group by` in your query to "remove" duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removeDuplicates($array) {
    $arr = [];   
    foreach ($array as $obj) {
       $arr[$obj->LastTask] = $obj;
    }

    return $arr;
}

$presents = removeDuplicates($presents);
```

or even like this:

```
function keyBy($array, $field) {
    $arr = [];   
    foreach ($array as $val) {
       $key = is_array($val) ? $val[$field] : $val->{$field};
       $arr[$key] = $obj;
    }

    return $arr;
}

$presents = keyBy($presents, 'LastTask');
```

Answer (score 7):

Use your `foreach` to assign the correct values to an array

```
$output = array();
foreach($presents as $present){
    $output[] = $present->LastTask;
}
```

Then use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to filter it.

```
$result = array_unique($output);
```

As mentioned in a comment, a better solution might be to alter the query so it uses a `GROUP BY` to only return unique LastTask values. This would be a better solution if and only if the other information in the query result (`$presents`) isn't used elsewhere.

Comment: Nice, but modifyiing the query seems to a better option here unless `$presents` has other uses..

Comment: I agree, in principle. The question's lacking in a lot of context that might make a query-based answer more suitable. I'll edit the answer to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 7, you can use `array_column` to re-index an array of objects using a specified field, which has the side-effect of removing duplicates. The advantage of this approach is that it keeps the full object as part of the array, in case other fields are also needed in your output:

```
$array = array_column($array, null, 'LastTask'));
```

See https://eval.in/896268